# Problem with audio sync when concatenating multiple mp4(s)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate up to 4 (appx.  800MB) mp4/mkv videos at a time, losslessly, and preferably with little or no re-encoding.  All have similar,  but not identical, properties. The issue I am having is when I am able to concate any files, the audio of the latter videos becomes gradually more and more out of sync.

It seems I am having a fps and/or timestamp asyncronicity, but I am unsure.  I've been able to looslessly remux from mp4 with differing resolutions- to ts files,  then concate the ts files successfully into a new mp4, alas the audio sync issue.

I am relitively new to the concate scene and am limited to ONLY an android device,  therefor I am limited to FFmpeg CLI, and the FFmpeg media encoder apps for android.  All signs point to needing mkvmerge at the very least,  but I cannot find a comparable app for Android.

Can anyone suggest a solution exclusively for android?  And can anyone please explain how the fps and timestamp function/relate/can be modified,  in layman terms? I keep reading command switches (TBN, PTS,  etc...)  that I don't understand,  not to mention the syntax switches used to manipulate them.

Comment: This happens when some of the files have no audio or audio shorter than the video.

Comment: The problem exists with even only two, which both definitely have audio from start to finish:

Comment: Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.2.103
  Duration: 01:39:34.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1140 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x534 [SAR 801:800 DAR 12:5], 1049 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 83 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:

Comment: Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.9.100
  Duration: 01:48:04.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1175 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x534 [SAR 801:800 DAR 12:5], 1049 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 27021 tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)

Comment: Same resolution,  different fps, tbn?,  and tbc? This is just one example of my conundrum. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: If it is merely a difference in lengths obetween audio and video,  how's would I go about matching them appropriately, without re-encoding? (Android friendly only)